# mysqldump - Access denied for user

Tags: command-line, mysql

When I run the following command from an open windows command shell (Win7), it works fine, and the backup is written to my file system. The MySQL database is on a remote linux server.

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqldump" -h *******.com -u ******* -p***** --databases ******* > "C:\******\_Database\backups\DB_%date:~0,3%.bak"
```

But when I put the same command into a batch file (whatever.bat) and run the bat file (with a "pause" command at the end), I get the error "Got error: 1045: Access denied for user '**me**'@'c-24-2-64-138.hsd1.ut.comcast.net' (using password: YES) when trying to connect".

Why does it work from inside an open command shell, but not when running from a bat file? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should escape the password using single quotes: `-p'password'`.

The correct command would be:

```
"mysqldump" -h *******.com -u ******* -p'*****' --databases ******* > "C:\******\_Database\backups\DB_%date:~0,3%.bak"
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been experiencing a similar problem. I have 4 databases all which back up fine. The 5th would not backup no matter what user I attempted with - even root. It turns out the ^ symbol in the password was the problem for me. Once I changed the users password to include ! rather than ^ everything worked immediately.

Comment: As others pointed out, enclosing the password in quotes did the trick for me (I kept the password in my.cnf file).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out this exasperating thing. The problem was my password itself: 4$5%6^^7^&deZeYPdx5014VB3C#

When I changed that password, everything worked. Some character in there jacks up windows batch file execution. I suspect it's the % sign, but hard to know. Must be a bug in windows, given the fact that it works fine from command shell but not in bat file OR cmd file.

Comment: There is no 'bug' here. Some characters have special meaning in batch files (just like any other programming/scripting language) to enable various kinds of programmability.

Comment: When specified in a BASH script, using parameter substitution, the parameter should be enclosed in SINGLE quotes, in order to prevent additional evaluation of a string that contains a combination of symbols and letters ($ being a problem here).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `--user=**** --password=****`?

I recall having some issues getting mysqldump to pick up the username and password in scripts, and found that this setting worked. Sorry, but I'm afraid I cannot remember more about what the issues were or what caused them...

Comment: amaidment: I tried your suggestion but I still get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SweatCoder - apologies, typo on my part - amended accordingly. Glad you got it working.

Comment: I didn't get it working. I just know that == doesn't work. Still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: @SweatCoder - have you tried with single '=' ? I use this format, so know it works (on my box).

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, previously the password wasn't being accepted so tried it without the quotes around the password...

Here's what I used
mysqldump -h localhost -u username -ppassword --databases databasename > "C:\backups\dbbkup.%DATE:/=%.bak"